¿Cómo obtener la fecha y la hora del servidor de base de datos con SQL Server y Entity Framework Core?
Desde .NET Framework, para obtener la fecha y la hora actuales desde el servidor de base de datos definía una propiedad en el contexto de la siguiente manera (en VB.NET):
    Public ReadOnly Property FechaActual As Date
        Get
            Return CType(Me.ObjectContext.CreateQuery(Of Date)("CurrentDateTime()").Execute(MergeOption.NoTracking), ObjectResult(Of Date)).First()
        End Get
    End Property

Con Entity Framewor Core esto ya no es posible. Entiendo que se puede abrir directamente una conexión con la base de datos (DbConnection) y enviar la consulta mediante un comando (DbCommand), pero quisiera saber si hay alguna otra forma recomendada para obtener dicha fecha y hora.

Yo lo haría por medio de una vista, algo así:
Nota: voy a usar una base de datos SQLite, pero el método funciona con cualquiera
1.- Creo la Vista en el SQL
CREATE VIEW Info AS SELECT datetime() as HoraSQL

Este paso puede variar la forma en crear la vista según el motor de base de datos. Y seguramente también cambia la función que retorna la hora/fecha, que en el caso de SQLite es con datetime()
En esta misma vista podría incluir otros datos de información que necesites (además de la hora)
2.- La clase Info
Public Class Info
    Public Property HoraSQL As DateTime
End Class

3.- DbContext
Si creas la tabla tal cual como yo lo he puesto, deberás configurar que no tiene key
Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As ModelBuilder)
    modelBuilder.Entity(Of Info)(
       Sub(eb)
           eb.HasNoKey()
       End Sub)
   OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder)
End Sub

Como es una entidad única, aquí mismo en el DbContext pondría una función para retornar la hora
Public ReadOnly Property HoraSQL As DateTime
   Get
       Return Me.Info.First().HoraSQL
   End Get
End Property

4.- Invocación
Luego fácilmente se puede llamar:
dim hora = Me.ObjectContext.HoraSQL 


Gracias, Yussef.
Finalmente lo implementé mediante una DbConnection, para no modificar la base de datos en cada instalación.

Finalmente lo implementé mediante una DbConnection directa contra a base de datos.
Aquí está el código, por si a alguien le interesa. En el mismo código del contexto agregué la siguiente función:
        public DateTime FechaActual
    {
        get
        {
            var connection = this.Database.GetDbConnection();
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "SELECT GETDATE() As CurrentDateTime";
                var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
                if (result!=null && result != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    return (DateTime)result;
                } else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("La consulta para obtener la fecha y hora actual no devolvió un valor válido.");
                };
            }

        }
    }

